# Modeling Correlated Binary Data

Tags: binary-data, glmm, sas, generalized-estimating-equations

I have data which looks like this:

Subject ID (unique identifier), Group (Treatment or Control), Eye (Left / Right), Outcome (Success / Failure).
The data is coming from a trial testing a new treatment for an eye condition (e.g, Cataract).

Every subject contribute 2 observations, from both his eyes, and therefore the data is correlated. I have 20 subjects in each group, thus I have 40 observations in each group.

I am trying to model the data using various methods, and to learn from it on the differences between GLMM and GEE in general and in SAS in particular.

I tried the following models:

```
proc glimmix data = Example1;
class Group ID;
model outcome(event='1') = Group / dist = binary solution;
random int / sub = ID;
lsmeans Group / ilink;
run;

proc glimmix data = Example1 ;
class ID Group Eye;
model outcome(event='1') = Group / dist=binary solution;
random Eye / residual type=unr subject=ID ;
lsmeans Group / ilink;
run;

proc genmod data=Example1 descending;
class Group ID;
model outcome = Group / dist=bin;
repeated subject=ID / type=cs covb corrw;
run;
```

Each model gave somehow different results. This is a simulation exercise, so I do know the REAL proportions of success and failure, and also the correlation within subject.

I have multiple questions to ask you guys:

1. The basic one - is my code correct, did I actually use GLMM and GEE properly here ?
2. I understand that I can use PROC GLIMMIX to model GEE, how do I do that ? Will I get similar results to GENMOD ?
3. What is the difference between GEE and an "R Side" GLMM ? More specifically, what is the difference between my second model and GEE ?
4. Which method should I use when modeling a G side GLMM ? I got different results when going from quad to laplace, and the default (none of them) was the closest to the real values. Is there a way to compare all sorts of models (different methods, GEE,...)? I understand that AIC and BIC are not always a good source.

If you can add any info and details which will help me understand what and how to use, and when, it will be very appreciated. I do know the basic difference between GEE and GLMM (i.e. marginal vs. conditional).

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to get answer if you described your model with something more than SAS code.

Comment: I have described the variables I have at the top of the question. I have a binary outcome (1/0), two comparison groups, and correlation between observations (every subject contributes 2 observations). Some of my questions are theoretical, like what are the differences between GEE and an R-Side mixed model. My models are simply G-side mixed model, R-side mixed model and GEE.